# How do I set the http proxy in a subshell launched from a windows service

Tags: windows, http, proxy, service, authenticode

I am writing a windows service which takes an uploaded file, runs signtool.exe on it to do the signing and timestamping and then serves the signed file back.

The code for this works when run as a standalone server using twisted however if I try and run it as a service it fails with the error "Signing succeeded, but an error occurred while attempting to timestamp".

If I replace the signcode subprocess call with a curl.exe call which explicitly uses the proxy then this succeeds.

I have set the proxy in internet explorer and running the command manually works.  Is there another way of setting an http proxy for signtool/signcode or another way of doing this (I am keen for it to be a service for ease of integration in to some other monitoring systems)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but running signtool via cygwin ssh (using a password). The timestamping only works via the proxy and over ssh if I login at least once through the gui (e.g. via rdesktop). I don't even have to be logged in to the gui after that for it to work via ssh, I just have to make sure I login at least once via the gui. Whatever it's doing upon graphical login survives a reboot too. One difference however is that I'm setting the proxy settings dynamically using the same powershell that I'm launching via ssh :

```
$reg_key = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set-ItemProperty -path $reg_key ProxyServer -value 192.168.0.3:8888
Set-ItemProperty -path $reg_key ProxyOverride -value "<local>"
Set-ItemProperty -path $reg_key ProxyEnable -value 1
```

I tried launching explorer.exe &, notepad &, and iexplorer.exe & from ssh but it didn't help. I'll see about hard coding the proxy settings and also if its possible to have the signing user be logged into the gui after boot. Also will check to make sure ssh is launched with cygrunsrv -i or that it's allowed to interact with the desktop is checked in services.

The system reverts its image if it's halted (vmware delta image) (that's how I'm able to duplicate the problem), but I can always change it, which it looks like I might have to do to figure out this problem.

**Finally figured it out with some help from the comment here :**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2013/05/09/user-proxy-settings-showing-up-in-local-system-account-correct-way-to-apply-proxy-settings.aspx#10606266

Looks like the setting actually has to be set in the binary file :

```
HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings
```

This binary file doesn't get created in the registry until after graphical login even with the powershell settings I made above. Easiest way is to login (assuming you have the registry settings I made with powershell above, or set it manually through the internet options ui in the gui), export the HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections path, and the import it with :

```
regedit /s path_to_proxy_settings.reg
```

If you want it to apply for all users you need to apply the same file under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections
```

as mentioned in the post. There may be other ways as mentioned here https://serverfault.com/questions/34940/how-do-i-configure-proxy-settings-for-local-system , but the above was the easiest for me.